# Can only register one HTTP router in traefik

Tags: traefik

If I apply my docker-compose once it deploys it and it works.

If I deploy it a second time the HTTP Router in the Traefik UI is gone but a new HTTP Service is created.
So two HTTP Services but no HTTP Routers. I want 2 HTTP Routers for each deployment.

```
        - "traefik.backend=test"
        - "traefik.http.routers.test.rule=Host(`name-123-test.127.0.0.1.xip.io`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.test.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.docker.network=web"
        - "traefik.enable=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

from the configs above, it seems that your missing these labels

```
- traefik.http.services.test.loadbalancer.server.port=YOUR_PORT
- traefik.http.routers.test.service=test
```

ALSO `- "traefik.backend=test"` is not needed at all